# Floating point exception (core dumped) - Non-square numbers finder

Tags: c, exception, point, floating

i have a problem. I've been making this for hours, and i finally thought i had a draft, i solved a few mistakes i made, but now it's typing out "Floating point exception (core dumped)" when i run it. I was able to solve a few other issues, but I don't think i can get over this one without basically starting from scratch, i have no idea what could be causing this, i wonder if any more knowledgeable people here could take a look and try to spot a possible mistake. My program is supposed to find Non-square numbers - numbers not divisible by squares of whole numbers. It first finds squares to divide by, and then divides Non-square number candidates up to a specified integer. Then it types out all the numbers it finds. I think it's quite possible i've made a mistake in pointer usage, i have not yet quite mastered those, and most likely couldn't solve a related issue anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isNonSq (int a,int sqr) {
    int b=0.75*a;
    for (int i=2;i<b;i++) {
        if (a%sqr[i]==0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main ( void ) {
    int a;
    int * resNum;
    int * sqr;
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        if (scanf(" %d",&a)!=1||a<=0) {
            printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
            return 0;
        } else {
            int b, c=1;
            b=0.75*a;
            resNum=(int)malloc(a*sizeof(resNum));
            sqr=(int)malloc(a*sizeof(*sqr));
            for (int i=2;i<sqrt(a);i++)
                sqr[i]=pow(i,2);
            for (int i=1;i<b;i++) {
                if (isNonSq(i,sqr)) {
                    resNum[c]=i;
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=1;i<a;i++) {
        printf(" %d",resNum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(resNum);
    free(sqr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "i have no idea what could be causing this". That's what a debugger is for. Run your program in a debugger and at a minimum it will tell you the exact line of code that triggers the exception. You can also use the debugger to step thru the code and examine the variables as it runs.

Comment: `resNum=(int)malloc(asizeof(resNum));` What is `asizeof`? I suspect that isn't allocating the right size. And the cast is wrong as `resNum` is an `int *` not an `int`. Just remove it as it is unnecessary to cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: What is the `a` suffix on `int b=0.75a;`? Is there a missing `*` or something?

Comment: From kaylum if a pointer is 8 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes then the cast will spoil the pointer. So the cast would be *damaging* rather than unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This could be occurring because of an NaN or an infinite number, I would recommend you use gdb to figure out what is happening when you run your compiled c code.  [https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_gdb.php](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/howto_gdb.php)

Goodluck!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).